# pausing/ Unpausing in Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

This is the part of mine snake game code that I'm trying to change so I can pause, I'm managing to pause with it, but I'm failing in unpausing(the game freezes), I'm trying to use the key p to pause and u to unpause(the previous keys are for movement and quitting, they function as intended). Any way to do that without freezing? Also, any explanation on why it's not working now is welcomed.

```
while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quiting()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                # Choose direction by user input, block opposite directions
                key_right = event.key in (pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_d)
                key_left = event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_a)
                key_down = event.key in (pygame.K_DOWN, pygame.K_s)
                key_up = event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_w)
                if key_right and direction != "L":
                    direction = "R"
                elif key_left and direction != "R":
                    direction = "L"
                elif key_down and direction != "U":
                    direction = "D"
                elif key_up and direction != "D":
                    direction = "U"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    quiting()  # It will quit when esc is pressed
                while event.key == pygame.K_p: # Pausing
                    if event.key == pygame.K_u:  # Unpausing
                        break
```

Comment: The reason that you can't un-pause your game is because once you enter the `event.key == pygame.K_p` loop, then the value of `event.key` will never be able to change and thus `event.key` will always remain `pygame.K_p`.

Comment: Oh I see so I have to add  ```for event in pygame.event.get():``` again inside the pausing loop? @ChristianDean

Comment: don' use `while` but set variable `paused = True` and use this variable to skip functions which moves objects. And it will look like it is paused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `while` but variable `paused = True` to control functions which move object

```
paused = False

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get()

          if event.key == pygame.K_p: # Pausing
              paused = True
          if event.key == pygame.K_u:  # Unpausing
              paused = False

    if not paused:
        player.move()
        enemy.move()
```

If you want to use one key to pause/unpause

```
    if event.key == pygame.K_p: # Pausing/Unpausing
        paused = not paused
```

Answer (score 2):

Furas's method works well, but here is an alternate method that you could use when your project grows larger.

Effectively you set an attribute called `self.toggle` on your sprites, and only when that toggle attribute if False and a key is pressed is when your player can move. When the key to pause is pressed, `self.toggle` becomes True and you cannot move anymore.

E.x:

```
class Thing():
    self.toggle = True

# Some lines later...

if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and not thingsprite.toggle:
    # Move Code here

# Some lines later

if keys[pygame.K_TAB]:
    thingsprite.toggle = True
    # Therefore thingsprite cannot move left anymore
    # Alt method if you have more than one sprite
    for sprite in spritegroup:
         sprite.toggle = True
```

Answer (score 0):

by using pygame and pyttsx3

```
from pygame import mixer
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
  
say = 'getting details of current voice'
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')      
# engine.setProperty('volume',1.0)    
engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)  
engine.setProperty('rate', 200)     # setting up new voice rate
outfile = "temp.wav"
engine.save_to_file(say, outfile)
# engine.say("answer is -----------------------------   t1 less than t2 for question the time taken to switch")
engine.runAndWait()
  
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("temp.wav")
mixer.music.play()


def stop():
    mixer.music.stop()

def pause():
    mixer.music.pause()

def unpause():
    mixer.music.unpause()

 
while True:
      
    print("Press 'p' to pause, 'r' to resume")
    print("Press 'e' to exit the program")
    query = input("  ")
      
    if query == 'p':
        pause() 
    elif query == 'r':
        unpause() 
  
    elif query == 'e':
        mixer.music.stop()
        break
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).