# Where should I put my pause key at or located at?

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.7

Okay so I started a project today where I created Space Invaders. The only I'm personally having issues with is the pause and unpause button. I'm using Python 3.7.4 and Pygame 1.9.6.

```
paused = False
running = True
while running:
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_p:  # Pausing
            paused = True
        if event.key == pygame.K_u:  # Unpausing
            paused = False
if not paused:
    # RGB =  Red, Green, Blue
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # Background Image
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

            # if keystroke is pressed check whether its right or left
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if bullet_state is "ready":
                    bullet_Sound = mixer.Sound('laser.wav')
                    bullet_Sound.play()
                    # Get the current x coordinate of the spaceship
                    bulletX = playerX
                    fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0
```

So I don't know if I should have the pause button first or not.

I've tried:

```
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             running = False
         if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:  # Pausing
                paused = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_u:  # Unpausing
                paused = False
    if not paused:
        while running:
         '''The rest of the code'''
```

Where the # Pausing is:

I've tried:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_p:
    paused = not paused  # for pause and unpausing
```

No 'u' key.
So I'm just lost on where I should put it at. So it would be nice with the help. I looked at question: [pausing/ Unpausing in Pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761364/pausing-unpausing-in-pygame) for help. So anything else let me know.

Comment: You should only process the events in one place. Typically your game loop should be: process events ⇛ update game state ⇛ draw screen. Then you should ignore non-quit events when paused

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal, complete example of a ball moving. You can pause and unpause its movement by pressing <kbd>P</kbd>. You can change its speed using <kbd>←</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>. Pressing <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> will reset the speed.

```
import pygame

WIDTH = 640
HEIGHT = 480
FPS = 30


class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """Moving ball sprite"""

    def __init__(self, color="white", size=20, speedx=-5, speedy=-5):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.color = pygame.color.Color(color)
        # instead of loading an image from file, draw a circle.
        self.image = pygame.Surface((size * 2, size * 2), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        pygame.draw.circle(self.image, self.color, (size, size), size)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # start ball in the middle of the screen
        self.rect.x = WIDTH / 2 - self.rect.width / 2
        self.rect.y = HEIGHT / 2 - self.rect.height / 2
        self.speedx = speedx
        self.speedy = speedy
        self.size = size

    def update(self):
        # reverse direction if out of bounds
        if not (0 < self.rect.x < WIDTH - self.size*2):
            self.speedx *= -1
        if not (0 < self.rect.y < HEIGHT - self.size*2):
            self.speedy *= -1
        # update position
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        self.rect.y += self.speedy


pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

ball = Ball()
balls = pygame.sprite.Group()
balls.add(ball)


paused = False
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                paused = not paused
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                ball.speedy += 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                ball.speedy -= 5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                ball.speedx += 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                ball.speedx -= 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                # reset speed
                ball.speedx = 2
                ball.speedy = 0
    # update game elements
    if not paused:
        pygame.display.set_caption('Running')
        ball.update()
    else:
        pygame.display.set_caption('Paused')
    # draw surface - fill background
    window.fill(pygame.color.Color("grey"))
    ## draw sprites
    balls.draw(window)
    # show surface
    pygame.display.update()
    # limit frames
    clock.tick(FPS)
pygame.quit()
```

Note that whilst paused, events are still being handled, so you can still adjust the speed. To change this behaviour, you'd need to discard specific events when `paused` is `True`.